# Is is possible to delete DLC from Steam?

Tags: steam, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2

Is there any way of removing DLC (Downloadable Content) from a game in Steam?

In particular, I want to remove the two map packs from Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 2 as playlists are segregated depending on whether you have the DLC or not.

I don't mind having to remove the DLC permanently and losing what I paid for as long as I can get rid of the DLC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't remove the DLC (or choose not to install it) once you've purchased it.  You can contact Steam support (as I noted in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/44930/13845)) and ask them to remove items from your library, and they will generally do so.  Do note that you'll never be able to get this back again without paying, however.

In most of my CoD experiences, the map pack playlists are separate from the base game playlists, so you may just be mistaken about not being able to play with people who don't have the packs.  You should still have access to the base game playlists even when the map packs are installed.

Another route might be attempting to remove the DLC files from your machine.  I don't have this game on Steam to test this theory, but I believe the map pack files are stored in two locations:

In your Steam folder, look for `steamapps` - in this folder, there should be some *.ncf files that correspond to the map packs, for example:

`steamapps\call of duty modern warfare 2 resurgence pack.ncf`

You might try removing this file and seeing if the map pack no longer registers.  There are also related files in:

`steamapps\common\call of duty modern warfare 2\zone\dlc`

I'd suggest backing any candidate files up by copying them to some other location before you delete the versions in steamapps.  However, the worst case scenario is probably just that you have to run Steam's verify utility if you delete a file you shouldn't have.

Comment: I'm re-installing it now so when it installs I can check to see if this works.

Comment: i asked the steam support do delete my black ops 2 dlc but they didnt respond...

Comment: The SSA grants you the right to terminate any subscription at any time. So they have to delete any game or dlc you purchased without questions asked. `You may cease use of a Subscription at any time or, if you choose, you may request that we terminate your access to a Subscription.` http://store.steampowered.com/subscriber_agreement/

Answer (score 0):

If possible, just go to properties, DLC and discard the DLC you want (uncheck it) and the dlc itself will be undone